# Appearance of jquery select2 on regular textbox

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I have a number of fields in a form, some of which are select boxes or autosuggest boxes. For those I already set up the jQuery select2 plug-in. But there are other fields which are text boxes or date-picker boxes. It would improve the appearance of the form if the select2 appearance would apply to them too.
I don't want select2 functionality on those fields, just the appearance. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use your developers' tools to check the css properties on the select2 box and add those properties to the other select boxes on your stylesheet.

It's that easy ;-)